# Admob swift loadRequest issue

Tags: xcode, swift, admob, ads, interstitial

compiler Showing me this message every time

To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];

And the ads did not appear

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var interstitial = GADInterstitial()
    interstitial.delegate = self
    interstitial.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx"

    var Request  = GADRequest()
    Request.testDevices = [ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ] // not working i don't know why ?!
    interstitial.loadRequest(Request)
```

Comment: there is good article about that http://notnow.uno/2015/08/26/swift-in-admob/